# Clicking Membership on View Contact Throws Error won't display page

Tags: civimember, joomla, error

Recently upgraded to civicrm 4.7.11 
On joomla 3.6.2  php 5.6.23  mysql 5.6.29

I have just noticed when I click memberships Civicrm throws a unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again.

I am able to click on contributions activities and events.

When I turn on logging and look at the log I'm getting in CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CiviCRM_API3_Exception))

["error_message"]=>
      string(41) "Expected one PaymentProcessor but found 0"
      ["error_code"]=>

I have two payment processors setup. One that I have had for some time and another I just created after this issue. They each have a row for the production and test. Only think I can think of is the payment processor id field starts at 7.

I haven't seen anything else on this.  Must be something specific on my site.
We have been running civicrm joomla 5 years now.

Comment: please try to look for detailed error message in civicrm log file - if not look for any php error - that might help you

Answer (score 2):

Donald, Could you help us with

1. From which version of CiviCRM did you upgrade to 4.7.11?
2. Are you using any payment processor extension like iAts, etc?
3. Could you check in db if you get 0 results by running the query below

   `SELECT ccr.payment_processor_id FROM civicrm_contribution_recur ccr 
   LEFT JOIN civicrm_payment_processor cpp ON cpp.id = ccr.payment_processor_id 
   WHERE cpp.id IS NULL
   GROUP BY ccr.payment_processor_id`
4. Could you also paste the result of below query?

   `SELECT cr.payment_processor_id as ppID1, cp.payment_processor as ppID2
     FROM civicrm_membership mem
   INNER JOIN civicrm_membership_payment mp  ON ( mem.id = mp.membership_id )
   INNER JOIN civicrm_contribution       con ON ( mp.contribution_id = con.id )
   LEFT JOIN civicrm_contribution_recur cr  ON ( mem.contribution_recur_id = cr.id )
   LEFT JOIN civicrm_contribution_page  cp  ON ( con.contribution_page_id  = cp.id )`

Thanks
Pradeep

Comment: 1) Was on previous version 4.7.10.  Upgrade and database upgrade completed without incident.  2) Using no payment processor extensions just what comes with civicrm we have been on paypal standard.  I am separately having issues with the IPN coming back but not updating the status of memberships.  I mention this but don't have reason to believe it is related. 3. MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).  4.  I get 4509 total rows either NULL NULL, NULL 3, or NULL 7.  Can't paste that many rows, happy to send other way. Pls advise

Comment: Can paste result for 


1. Select payment_processor_id FROM civicrm_contribution_recur GROUP BY payment_processor_id;

Comment: And also for

Select payment_processor_id FROM civicrm_contribution_page;

Check if you see payment_processor_id that are not equal to civicrm_payment_processor.id

Comment: Select payment_processor_id FROM civicrm_contribution_recur GROUP BY payment_processor_id;   Returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0016 seconds.)

Comment: Select payment_processor FROM civicrm_contribution_page Returned  NULL
NULL
NULL
3
3
3
3
3
7

Comment: So you have id 3 and 7 present in civicrm_payment_processor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45710/discussion-between-pradeep-nayak-and-donald-knapp).

Answer (score 1):

I would check to see which Payment Processors are enabled on the Membership form.  In Manage Contributions you will find the Membership one, look at the Amounts Tab (even though it's grayed out) and be sure a valid Payment processor is checked.

Comment: On the Manage Contribution Page I have checked the Amounts tab.  The payment processor is checked.  Note this contribution page was set up months ago.  I am currently just inquiring on a membership by clicking memberships from View Contacts when this blows up.

Comment: I am.   I did this from memory :)   Fixed the answer.   If that does not do it - I'd create a new processor (even test) and switch to that for testing.  I have had times were the payment processor was the problem.   I don't have a joomla install to test on.   Do you get any error mesages in the CiviCRM log files? (Beyond what is noted above)

Comment: Tried that.  Ran clean up caches as well.  Didn't fix it. Add this to the mix,  I go to the membership dashboard and can pull up a list of all my current memberships.  I can view and edit each one.  I have 673 memberships.  When I get to 601-650 the second to the last page and try to go next to the last page it blows up.  These 673 are all current the last ones are the oldest, from mid May of this year.

Comment: Let me add that the dashboard shows I have 659 current members yet when I click on all current members (659), I get:                                      672 Results  
Membership Status In Current, 3, Pending for Next Academic Year     along the top.  Those counts are off.

Comment: I took a look at the membership table and I have 12 memberships listed current that shouldn't be.  I have manually set the status id on these to 4 (Expired).  Now my dashboard shows the right number and I can scroll to the end without a problem.  I can view and edit any membership from here as well.  I still cannot get to membership tab from the contact screen.